# How to count words (do not count series of special char) using scanner, loop,array,if and else statement

Tags: java

How to count words (do not count series of special char) using scanner, loop, array, if and else statement?

It's not finished yet because I don't know how! Could anyone help me?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    System.out.println("Simple Java Word Count Program");

    String str1 = null;

    char ch;
    int sample = 0;
    int i;
    int j = 0;
    int k = 0;
    int wordCount = 1;
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter your quote:");
    str1 = in.nextLine();

    for (i = 0; i < str1.length(); i++)
    {
      if (str1.charAt(i) == ' ' && str1.charAt(i + 1) != ' ')
      {
        String[] arr = str1.split(" ");

        for (k = 0; k < ;)
        {
          for (j = 0; j < arr[i].length(); j++)
          {
            ch = arr[i].charAt(j);

            if (Character.isLetterOrDigit(ch))
            {
              wordCount++;
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }

    System.out.println("Word count is = " + wordCount);
  }
}
```

Comment: declare String [] arr just after your str1 = in.nextLine(); is called; then fill it as you're doing it, but last 2 for cicle must be out of the 1st one. And for(k=0;k<;) doesn't works for anything, just run all array and print it with "System.out.println("Array[j]= "+arr[j]);" and that's it!

Comment: Why not count the number of spaces and then the number of words would be 1 more than the number of spaces?

Answer (score 2):

```
String string = "Simple Java Word Count Program";

String[] words = string.split("\\s+");

System.out.println("Words Count: " + words.length);
```

Good thing is now you can even use `words` by `indexes`. First word in the `string` would be `words[0]`, second word would be `words[1]` and so on.

Other method is to count the number of spaces instead, and then number of words would be 1 more than the number of spaces (in an ideal world):

```
String string = "Simple Java Word Count Program";
string = string.trim();

int spaceCount = 0;
for(int i = string.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
  if(string.charAt(i) == ' ')
  {
    spaceCount++;
  }
}

System.out.println("Words Count: " + (spaceCount + 1));
```

If there are multiple spaces between two words, then the above `spaceCount` method will fail.
To prevent that from happening, use this simple technique:

```
String string = "  Simple  Java   Word  Count  Program ";
string = string.trim();

int spaceCount = 0;
boolean isLastCharSpace = false;
for(int i = string.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
  if(string.charAt(i) == ' ')
  {
    if(!isLastCharSpace)
    {
      spaceCount++;
      isLastCharSpace = true;
    }
  }
  else
  {
    isLastCharSpace = false;
  }
}

System.out.println("Words Count: " + (spaceCount + 1));
```

Now this will print the correct word count, without using any extra memory, unlike the first method, and without falling in any pitfall of multiple consecutive spaces between words, unlike the second method.

If you have series of special characters included in your string and if they are attached with words, then there will be no issue. If they are not attached with words, and are independently existing in your string, then there will be some discrepancy in the answers of program and real answer. One can even write code similarly to prevent such situation from happening, and to provide exactly correct answer. Here's how such method would look like:

```
String string = "  Simple  Java -  Word,  {Count  Program} ";
string = string.trim();

string = removeAllSpecialCharacters(string);

int spaceCount = 0;
boolean isLastCharSpace = false;
for (int i = string.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
  if (string.charAt(i) == ' ')
  {
    if (!isLastCharSpace)
    {
      spaceCount++;
      isLastCharSpace = true;
    }
  }
  else
  {
    isLastCharSpace = false;
  }
}

System.out.println("Words Count: " + (spaceCount + 1));
```

And here's `removeAllSpecialCharacters` method:

```
private String removeAllSpecialCharacters(String string)
{
  StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

  for (int i = 0; i < string.length(); i++)
  {
    char ch = string.charAt(i);

    // Allow only letters, digits, and spaces.
    if (Character.isLetterOrDigit(ch) || ch == ' ')
    {
      stringBuilder.append(ch);
    }
  }

  return stringBuilder.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 String s = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";

int totalWords = 0;

for(String current: s.split("\\s+")){
    totalWords++;
}

System.out.println(totalWords);
```

EDIT:

We can disregard the special characters in word count by using a different regex.

```
String s = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";

int totalWords = 0;

for(String current: s.split("[^A-z]+")){
  totalWords++;
}

System.out.println(totalWords);
```

Comment: Now this regex even disregards digits. ;)

Answer (score 0):

If i understood your question right, this is one way of doing it:

```
package eclipsePackage;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class hehe {
    public static void main(String[] args){

        Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("enter a sentence");
        String str1=in.nextLine();
        int wordCount=0;
        str1.trim();

        for(int i=0;i<str1.length();i++){
            if(str1.charAt(i)==' ')
                wordCount++;
        }

        wordCount++;
        System.out.println(wordCount);
    }
}
```

logic: first trim the sentence to remove any unneeded white spaces, then use a for loop to count the no of black spaces, the no of words in the sentence will be one more than that.

Comment: It should be `str1 = str1.trim();`. You should even close your `scanner` in the end. Also, what if the input string is `"Hey  check out  the   multiple spaces   in between me!";`?

Comment: yeah sorry
if its more than one black space then:
boolean LastCharSpace=false; 
if(!LastCharSpace){
wordCount++;
LastCharSpace=true;
}

Answer (score 0):

I think the following may address your needs. If all you want is to know the "number" of words, it seems sufficient to look at the "length" field within the generated array from String.split(regex).

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SplitJava {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter something: ");
        String str = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Number of words in '" + str + "': " + str.split("\\s+").length);
        scanner.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: You should even close the `scanner` in the end to prevent memory leaks.

Comment: That's a good point. Well, since the scanner is wrapping System.in it's not clear that closing won't just be a no-op (System.in is always available for reading input), but it's good practice.