# In a recursive way, how do I count the number of words in a char array in java?

Tags: java, arrays, recursion

My project is to count the number of words in a char array in a recursive way.

```
//Code:
public static int countWords(char[] array) {
    if (array == null)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("The received array is null");

    char[] array_new = trimLeadingSpaces(array);

    //Arrays.copyOfRange(array_new, idxFirstSpace(array_new, 0), array_new.length);

    if(idxFirstSpace(array_new, 0) == 0)
        return 0;

    if(idxFirstSpace(array_new, 0) == array_new.length)
        return 1;

    return 0;
}

}
```

I have two previous methods to take the first spaces in a char[]: trimLeadingSpaces(char[] array) (returns a char[]; example, we have a char[] like [  abc  ] and it returns [abc  ]) and another function to know the first index of the first ' ': idxFirstSpace(char[] array, int currentIdx) and returns  a int.
My problem is in the method countWords().

```
// test method coundWords
    test_coundWords("abc"); // = 1
    test_coundWords("  abc  "); // = 1
    test_coundWords(" abc  def"); // = 2
    test_coundWords(" abc def d"); // = 3
    test_coundWords("a a  def  d   g "); // = 5
    test_coundWords("   "); // = 0
    test_coundWords(""); // = 0
    test_coundWords(null); // = Erro: The received array is null
```

Console:

```
coundWords (abc) = 1
coundWords (  abc  ) = 2 //HERE IS THE PROBLEM
coundWords ( abc  def) = 2
coundWords ( abc def d) = 3
coundWords (a a  def  d   g ) = 5
coundWords (   ) = 0
coundWords () = 0
coundWords (null) = Erro: The received array is null
```

I CAN'T CHANGE THE METHOD and change the char[] to a string. It must work only with char arrays.

Comment: What if you try to split your char array ?

Comment: I can't change the char array into a string

Comment: So do I understand you correctly in that for `"  abc  "` your code returns 2 instead of 1? If so, did you debug your code, especially what happens when `trimLeadingSpaces()` returns an empty array or if `idxFirstSpace()` returns there is no space in the array?

Comment: Try to implement a method similar to `trimLeadingSpaces(array);` but to remove the ending spaces

Comment: I cant do that either @vincrichaud

Comment: @Thomas I did. The method works perfectly.

Comment: So to make it clear: you have to implement `int countWords(char[] array)` and must only use the two other methods provided?

Comment: If you verify if the first array position and the last position is empty and remove the positions if are.

Comment: "The method works perfectly." - I'd doubt that, since you'd not have any problem. To make it clearer: I assume `trimLeadingSpaces()` and `idxFirstSpace()` are doing what they are meant to do so it must be your code that does something wrong (e.g. like counting empty arrays at the end if there are trainling spaces).

Comment: yes @Thomas. What should I do?

Comment: @Ruca could you please edit your question to make it clear that you can use only certain method, and so what does these methods do

Comment: I second that, please add what `trimLeadingSpaces()` and `idxFirstSpace()` will do. Will `trimLeadingSpaces()` remove _all_ leading spaces? Will `idxFirstSpace()` return 0 or -1 if there are no spaces in the array?

Comment: I added @Thomas

Comment: @Ruca your last edit (deleting the methods you posted) makes your question very hard to understand and the comments and answers next to impossible to follow. Please roll back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you are interesting in recursive solution *(we're do not talk about performance)*, so your code is almost correct. This is modified example:

```
public static int countWords(char[] array) {
    if (array == null)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("The received array is null");

    char[] array_new = trimLeadingSpaces(array);

    if (array_new.length == 0)
        return 0;

    int nextSpacePosition = idxFirstSpace(array_new, 0);
    int count = 1;

    if (nextSpacePosition > 0 && nextSpacePosition < array_new.length)
        count += countWords(Arrays.copyOfRange(array_new, nextSpacePosition, array_new.length));

    return count;
}
```

***P.S.*** To be absolutely clear, I have used following implementations of `trimLeadingSpaces()` and `idxFirstSpace()`:

```
private static char[] trimLeadingSpaces(char[] arr) {
    String str = new String(arr);
    while (str.length() > 0 && str.charAt(0) == ' ')
        str = str.substring(1);
    return str.toCharArray();
}

private static int idxFirstSpace(char[] arr, int currentIdx) {
    return new String(arr).indexOf(' ', currentIdx);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use recursion here, but rather would just iterate through the character array while maintaining a small amount of state:

```
public static int countWords(char[] array) {
    boolean isSpace = true;
    int count = 0;

    for (int i=0; i < array.length; ++i) {
        if (array[i] != ' ' && isSpace) {
            ++count;
            isSpace = false;
        }
        else if (array[i] == ' ') {
            isSpace = true;
        }
    }

    return count;
}
```

### Demo

The basic idea here is that we keep track of when we have hit a space character, and when that happens, we increase the count by one upon hitting the start of a word (i.e. a single non space character).  Note that this space flag start off set to `true`, because the very first character in the array might be the start of a word.

Comment: That would be the more efficient way but since the OP seems to be under some constraints (I assume for learning purposes) and thus use of recursion might be one of them.

Comment: It's what I have to do... This in a recursive way but thanks

Comment: @Thomas Using recursion for this problem is very far from what I would do to handle it.

Comment: Exactly, just as I said (and the OP confirmed) using recursion seems to be set, i.e. there's no way around it for the task at hand.

Comment: @Thomas Stack Overflow isn't just about giving an answer to a homework problem, it's about the _best_ answer. The best answer here probably is to construct a `String` based on the character array and then use string functions.  The next best answer, if we're really stuck with a character array, is probably what I wrote above.  Recursion comes in a distance third, and someone who really has this problem probably won't want a recursive solution.

Comment: It's the project... I cant do nothing about that. If I was told to do recursion, I do recursion

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, if you change the question to your liking like this then the best cause is not to answer it but to close it like a duplicate. Here is one [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22124429/how-to-count-words-do-not-count-series-of-special-char-using-scanner-loop-arr)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is using `array.length` here: `return 1 + countWords(Arrays.copyOfRange(array_new, idxFirstSpace(array_new,  0), array.length - 1));`

With input `"  abc  "` `array_new` will eventually have length 0 but `array` will still have length 2 (because an array of 2 spaces was passed). Thus the terminator character `\0` will be added as per JavaDoc on `Arrays.copyOfRange()`:

> The final index of the range (to), which must be greater than or equal to from, may be greater than original.length, in which case '\u000' is placed in all elements of the copy whose index is greater than or equal to original.length - from.

Due to this you'll count the new array `['\0']` as another word. Change `array.length` to `array_new.length` and it should be fine.

Note that this shouldn't happen when using strings or should at least popup when stepping through your code with a debugger (you'd enter `countWords()` 3 times for the problematic input instead of 2 times only).